# Strange behavior in azure table

Tags: azure-table-storage

I was investigating performance of updates done to entity stored in azure tables and I observed some strange behavior.

I have a simple entity that consists of just one filed - Text like below:

```
public class TestEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

For this entity I see update times between **150 - 200ms** when deployed to azure.

Then I add **some dummy properties** to it (don't get me started how I came up with that idea ;)

```
public class TestEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp1{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp2{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp3{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp4{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp5{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp6{ get; set; }
     public string ShowSomeStuffProp7{ get; set; }
}
```

Now for this "new" entity I get update times between **30 - 45ms**!!!

I did some experiments (each time deploying to azure) and the "dummy" properties can't have shorter names - otherwise the time goes back to 200ms.

I'm wondering if I had gone mad or is that some strange behavior that was observed by someone else as well.

I still want to repeat that on another account, but I'd appreciate the feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: turns out this behavior is well known and documented http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx